# Laravel Artisan Error 'LARAVEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: testing, laravel

For the life of me I cannot work this one out, Fresh Laravel install ontop of WAMP (win7 64) appropriate path variables added etc and arisan is responding however if i run "php artisan test" I get:

'LARAVEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this commit, which breaks functionality in Windows: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/4046313ecd4934e09a621ee930ee31f88262475e

A solution given in the forum by Oli is to change the code in runner.php:

```
protected function test() {
    ...
    putenv('LARAVEL_ENV='.Request::env());
    passthru('phpunit --configuration '.$esc_path, $status);
    ...
}
```

You should be able to use `php artisan --env=test test` again